# Solr finds words without diacritics when searching with diacritics but not the other way around

Tags: solr

For my solr implementation I want the query to return the words with and withhout diacriticts regardless if you search with or without diacritics.

To give an example

The search word is "**çest**" - Solr returns: '*cest*', '*çest*' and '*çest ca*'
The search word is "**cest**" - Solr returns: '*cest*', '*çest*' and '*çest ca*'

Currenty the first works. When I search "çest" it returns both cest and çest. However when I search "cest" it returns only 'cest'

This is how it looks in my schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_special_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\W+" replacement="-"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Is there a way to let it work both ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want either matches, you don't need the `solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory`.
This would remove the special characters before they are passed to the ASCII filter.

You can use :-

```
<fieldType name="text_special_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

You can also use a WhiteSpace Tokenizer to have tokens and use Lower Case as a Filter.

Also, remember the order of execution in an Analyzer is as follows, irespective of the order you have :-

- CharFilters
- Tokenizer
- Filters

Answer (score 0):

The recommended answer never worked for me, instead I had to use this:

```
<fieldType name="text_special_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

You can also use the mapping file provided with your solr version or use the one linked below
https://github.com/lmjabreu/solr-conftemplate/blob/master/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt